# Gomoku diagolanl score allocation.

Tags: c++

So, I'm trying to create my own algorithm in Gomoku whereby when player1 
makes a move, where ever it placed its "x", the "x" would be allocated scores around it. For instance, if there is just 1 "x" that is not surrounded by any other "x", it will get a score of 3 above, beneath and on either sides of it. If an "x" is placed next to the same "x" then the score around it would increment. So, I'm having trouble with allocating the scores to the diagonal ends. I have to take many things into consideration and its making my code too long. Is there a way that I could make this code shorter?

Thanking everyone in advance.

```
if (coll==0 && roww==0 && boarDD[roww][coll]==1 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]!=1) //diag top left corner
            {
                if (boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                }
            }
            else if (roww==5 && coll==0 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]!=1 && boarDD[roww][coll]==1 )//diag bot left
            {
                if (boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
            }
            else if (roww==5 && coll==5 && boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]!=1 && boarDD[roww][coll]==1 )//bot right corner
            {
                if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                }
            }
            else if (roww==0 && coll==5 && boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]!=1 && boarDD[roww][coll]==1)//top right corner
            {
                if (boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                }
            }
            else if (roww==0 && coll!=5 && coll!=0 && boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]!=1 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]!=1 && boarDD[roww][coll]==1)// top row exc diag
            {
                if (boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                }
            }
            else if (coll==0 && roww!=5 && roww!=0 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]!=1 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]!=1 && boarDD[roww][coll]==1) //left row
            {
                if (boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
            }
            else if (roww==5 && coll!=0 && coll!=5 && boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]!=1 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]!=1 && boarDD[roww][coll]==1) //bot roww
            {
                if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                     boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
            }
            else if (coll==5 && roww!=0 && roww!=5 && boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]!=1 && boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]!=1 && boarDD[roww][coll]==1)//right col
            {
                if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                }
            }
            else if (roww!=0 && roww!=5 && coll!=0 && coll!=5 && boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]!=1 && boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]!=1 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]!=1 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]!=1 && boarDD[roww][coll]==1)
            {
                if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                     boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                     boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                     boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if(boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;

                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                }
                else if(boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3 && boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll-1]=3;
                }
                else if(boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll-1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww+1][coll+1]=3;
                }
                else if (boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]<3)
                {
                    boarDD[roww-1][coll+1]=3;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Can the score get larger than 3?

Comment: Yes, it can go up to 6, (that will be when there are 4 "x"s in line. I just showed this little part of the code